# How to connect Google App Engine to External Mysql db using Python

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ibm-cloud

I have been trying to connect my Python app running on Google App Engine with External MySQL db that has been running on IBM Cloud.
The same code runs perfectly fine with localhost but, when I Run it over App Engine it responds with 502 BAD GATEWAY error.
Is there any way to build this?

Below is the Simple code I've been trying

---

```
import pymysql.cursors  
# Connect to the database.
connection = pymysql.connect(host='XXXXXXX',
                             database='XXX',
                             user='XXX',
                             password='XXXX',
                             port=XXX)
print ("connect successful!!")
 try:
 with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # SQL 
        sql = "SELECT * from songs "
        # Execute query.
        cursor.execute(sql)
        print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)
        print()
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
 finally:
    # Close connection.
    connection.close()
```

---

Below is the error I'm getting in Google Cloud Logs

[image]

---

It's a Standard environment

[image]

_---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Any error messages in your logs? https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer

Comment: 1) What is reporting the 502 error? Your AppEngine Code, your browser, etc. 2) IBM Cloud Database for MySQL does not use an HTTP proxy. Double-check the IP address and Port number if the error is reported for the connect statement.

Comment: Below are the logs on Google Cloud Log Viewer:::::::
A 2020-09-15T21:42:38.375819Z connect successfully!! 
A 2020-09-15T21:42:38.394871Z {'song_id': 1, 'title': 'demons', 'artist': 'Imagine Dragons', 'genre': 'POP'} 
A 2020-09-15T21:42:38.395025Z {'song_id': 1, 'title': 'demons', 'artist': 'Imagine Dragons', 'genre': 'POP'} 
A 2020-09-15T21:42:38.395329Z Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'main'.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the required information, in the comment section the format isn't the required to have a good understanding of the information, also please add the specific error and where are you seeing it.

Comment: Thank you for updating the post, by looking at the error, the issue seems to be related with your code application rather than the MySQL connection. Are you using App Engine flex or standard? Please update your question with your `app.yaml` file and if possible the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code of your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pymysql.cursors

app = Flask(_name_)

# Annotation that direct app engine to / route.
@app.route('/')
def home():
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='XXXXXX',
                                database='XXXX',
                                user='XXXX',
                                password='XXXXX',
                                port=XXXX,
                                charset='utf8mb4',
                                cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

    print ("connect successful!!")

    try:

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            # SQL 
            sql = "select * from songs"
            
            # Execute query.
            cursor.execute(sql)
            print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)

            print()

            for row in cursor:
                print(row)
                
    finally:
        # Close connection.
        connection.close()

    return "Connection Sucessful"
if _name_ == '_main_':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entry point in app.yaml.
    app.run()
```

Here code will run only if it is not imported from other modules as you are checking for *name* = '**main**'.

Answer (score 0):

Its Working Now , I was not calling app() in google cloud engine , After modifying accordingly connection was successful

Modified COde with Insert SQL command :::::::

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import pymysql.cursors
#import logging

#from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

# Connect to th#e database.
@app.route('/')
def home():
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='XXXXXX',
                             database='XXXX',
                             user='XXXX',
                             password='XXXXX',
                             port=XXXX,
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
 
    print ("connect successful!!")
 
    try:
  
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # SQL 
            sql = "Insert into songs values(2,'Radioactive','Imagine Dragons','ROCK') "
         
            # Execute query.
            cursor.execute(sql)
        connection.commit()
            #print ("cursor.description: ", cursor.description)
 
            #print()
 
            #for row in cursor:
             #   print(row)
             
    finally:
        # Close connection.
        connection.close()
    
    return "Connection Sucessfull"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run()
```

Thanks So much for all the help !!